# Publish ASP.NET MVC app with SQL Server database to free Azure account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

Just want to know that I have my ASP.NET MVC application and related SQL Server database. I have signed up for a free Azure account.

I want to know if I can publish my app and database to Azure with this free account. The purpose of that, I want to check how the things are working properly and also since I working from home, selected user's want to see the progress of my project.

Comment: Well - have you tried? Just try and see !

Comment: @marc_s  Yes. I tried. From the Azure portal I have tried to create an App. and then it ask choose **pay as you go** or **existing subscription**. When I click **existing subscription**, it redirected to the dashboard again. From the VS I have tried to publish to the Azure, there I selected **Specific Target** as **Azure App Service** So then again it pop up the sign in form even I signed in the begining of the wizard, Then it dissaper.

Comment: Please open a [Billing Support](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/) ticket, they will be able to check this for you. Also refer this 
[Deploy an ASP. NET app to Azure with Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)
& [Create ASP.NET Web App With SQL Database In Azure](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/create-Asp-Net-web-app-with-sql-database-in-azure/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have paid subscription for SQL server feature. Try finding SQL server express also know that SQL server will separately require you to pay SQL server license key. I would suggest to look into free SQL server hosting accounts instead of directly using Azure SQL server.